# EJB: Passing instance of concrete class to an EJB method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

Lets say there is an EJB method that accepts an object implementing some interface.

```
MyStatelessBean.method(InterfaceA aObj);
```

So the server implements MyStatelessBean and the InterfaceA is available in its classpath.

Now the *concrete classes of InterfaceA are implemented at the Client side*. These concrete classes are **not** in the classpath of the server.

Now when the client makes a call to the server and passes an instance of the concrete class to EJB method,

```
InterfaceA concreteObjA = new InterfaceA() { ... }   
bean = context.lookup(ejbLookupStr);
bean.method(concreteObjA);
```

**what is the expected behavior?**

My testing in WildFly 9.0.2 resulted in ClassNotFoundException being reported in the Client side logs (but it seems like it is reporting a server side issue).

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.ktest.study.javaee.ejb.CallBackClient from [Module
>   "deployment.wildfly-ear.ear.wildfly-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]   at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:238)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.register(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.ktest.study.javaee.ejb.ClientObject.main(ClientObject.java:21)

Comment: The serialization mechanism requires object class to deserialize into. Without the class in its class path, the ejb receiver cannot deserialize the payload since it cannot find the type, hence classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Actually my requirement is server to client callback using RMI. The server provides CallBack Interface. But it's upto the Client to provide the concrete implementation. Since EJB uses serialization to pass objects from clients to server, it requires that the concrete class be available at server side for deserialization.

I had a bug in my RMI code which was causing the error.